# How to find the voltage on each of the parallel resistors?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors, parallel

Suppose we have a circuit like this:

[image]

It is easy to find the voltage on the node shared by the two parallel resistors, we simply have to find their equivalent resistance and use KVL. But the problem is that the voltage across each resistors should be different in theory, I've been figuring out how to manually calculate it, can anyone help me?

Edit: someone answered that the voltage is similar across each load. I get that, but how about in the case where we measure the node voltage with a voltmeter at 2 ohm. Wouldn't the 2 ohm be parallel to the shunt resistor in the voltmeter? if that were the case, then why would the voltmeter read a voltage lower than 10V?

Here's more examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "the voltage across the resistors should be different in theory"? What theory?

Comment: "*if that were the case, then why would the voltmeter read a voltage lower than 10V?*" What makes you think that is the case?

Comment: ayah sarcasm isn't what i need. people get it wrong, i'm a noob.

Comment: @DKNguyen I've been experimenting on circuitlab and that's what it shows.

Comment: Then you aren't doing what you think you're doing. Also "*But the problem is that the voltage across each resistors should be different in theory*" is not true.

Comment: We're not being sarcastic--we're trying to understand where your confusion is.

Comment: @DKNguyen Please look at the edits, I added the pic which caused my confusion.

Comment: And @Hearth sorry, i misunderstood, it jus subjectively felt sarcastic, been too stressed lately.

Comment: Those new images have R1 which is in series will drop some voltage coming from the source but after drop, the other parallel resistors have the same voltage. Turn up the decimal places and both circuits will have less than 10V across the parallel resistors. Just the 2 Ohm draws so much current through R1 it makes the drop more noticeable.

Comment: I hope you know that CircuitLab you use to draw these schematics automatically does DC analysis. Just hover the mouse over a node or a component and you’ll see voltages from the DC solution - and here DC is what you’re after. So you can easily check what “should be” happening so you don’t ask “why X happens” when X does *not* actually happen. In the 1st circuit there’s nothing to “solve”: only two nodes exist, and they are the terminals of an ideal voltage source. The voltage is 10V.

Comment: You seem confused by voltage dividers. The previous question of yours got that answered. You keep repeating the same question. Please don’t do that. Instead, ask for clarification under an answer if something’s unclear. You keep drawing the same circuit over and over again. In a circuit, the dashed boxes don’t affect function, by the way.

Answer (score 7):

The voltage across parallel resistors is the same for each resistor.

In your original image the voltage across R1 and R2 will be the same.

In your second image, the voltage across R4 and R5 will be the same.

In your third image you do not have two explicit resistors in parallel. However, the voltage across R4 and VM1 will be the same.

PS, if you disagree with an answer, why not leave a comment, instead of changing your question.

Answer (score 3):

If the 10 V source is "ideal", with no internal resistance, the voltage across R1 and across R2 will be 10 V.

If the 10 V source is "real", with some internal resistance, the voltages across R1 and across R2 will be identical, but less than 10 V, due to the voltage drop across the internal resistance of the 10 V source.